# Camera Troubles in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, visualization

I'm trying to animate a torus being cut by a plane, so that as the plane enters the torus the part in front of the plane disappears (the idea is to show the cross section). That much I can do, but I can't seem to get the camera to behave. I'd like everything to stay the same size and position, but despite setting `ViewVector`, `ViewAngle`, and `ViewVertical` the scene becomes smaller as the animation progresses. Note that I chose the settings pretty arbitrarily. I am baffled as to why the camera view changes with these three options fixed.

Here is the code (I produce the frames in a table, and then export them for the animation).

```
Table[Show[
  ContourPlot3D[(1 - Sqrt[x^2 + (y + 1/2)^2])^2 + z^2 - 1/4 == 
    0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2 - 2 t}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> False], (*The torus*)
  ContourPlot3D[y == 2 - 2 t, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> {White, Opacity[.5]}],         (*The plane*)
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> True, PlotRange -> All,
  ViewVector -> {{5 Sqrt[6], 10 Sqrt[6], 5 Sqrt[6]}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
  ViewAngle -> 3 Pi/50, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 1, .5}]
```

And here is the result.

[image: Torus cross sections]

As you can see, the camera zooms out and seems to rotate slightly. Any idea how to fix this?

(Edited to add `PlotRange -> All`)

Answer (score 10):

```
Table[Show[
  ContourPlot3D[(1 - Sqrt[x^2 + (y + 1/2)^2])^2 + z^2 - 1/4 == 
    0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2 - 2 t}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],(*The torus*)

  ContourPlot3D[y == 2 - 2 t, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> {White, Opacity[.5]}],(*The plane*)


  Axes -> False, Boxed -> True, 
  ViewVector -> {{5 Sqrt[6], 10 Sqrt[6], 5 Sqrt[6]}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
  ViewAngle -> 3 Pi/50, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 1, .5}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks. But I don't suppose you can tell what I'm misunderstanding with my approach?

Comment: @smackcrane The first element in the `Show[]` list determines the PlotRange ...

Comment: I was under the impression that `PlotRange->All` fixed that problem

Comment: Why is your animation all in pink like an error box?

Comment: @smackcrane you *can* set the `PlotRange` as an option of `Show` but `All` is variable.  If you use `PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}` it will work.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was about to correct a minor error in the code I used for generating the images, and then I thought it could be an indication that the code in the answer is not what I used to export the animated GIF. Perhaps the clue is not clear enough.